# Email to record Followers on every post or comment to the record

Tags: chatter, notification, chatter-feed, feedcomment, follow

I am not getting any chatter notification when I follow a record and if someone post or Comment to the chatter feed on the record.

Only when someone mentions (@User) then getting the notification or if some one replies after my comment to record

Here are my chatter settings below

[image]

[image]

Also Deleveribility Access is **All email**

Comment: can you check if you are getting regular notifications after you comment to a post?

Comment: @rao I am getting notification when someone comments after my post to the record

Comment: did you take a look at this article : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000170906&language=en_US  The articled says If a user that was “@” mentioned, does not make a comment to this post,  he/she will not receive any chatter email notifications with any new comments in the post.

Comment: @rao I looked into it but I want Email on Every chatter post on the record.

Comment: @rao There is an option (Email on each post) if user belongs to Group but not to a record.https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_email_notify.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Take a look at this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000icHyAAI Is this what you are looking for? I see that you cannot get email for every comment

Comment: @rao this is not possible.Here is the link https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000GwN7AAK

Comment: Yeah, this will make it appear on your "Feed", but no notification.   You'd have to write code or workflow to send email.   @ mentions are the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.Here is the idea link.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000GwN7AAK

Workaround is to use @Mention user if you want to send notification to user on the record.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in [Summer '17 release via Chatter Streams](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_collab_streamshome.htm). Users must first create or subscribe to a stream that includes the records and then have option to set notification to receive email on every post or not.

Learn more about **Chatter Streams** in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_chatter_streams_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

[image: screen shot]